# Form Field Verification Not Working

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, verification

I've got some form verification code that doesn't seem to be working correctly, and I can't figure out why.

```
function isTextFieldEmpty(textField){
    //return true or false depending on whether or not there is any text in the field

        console.log("Checking to see if the current field is empty...");

    var val = textField.value;          //val is the text from the current field
        console.log("The current value of 'val' is: " + val);
    if(val.length < 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

The error I get is: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"*.  Sure enough, my console log says that the value of 'val' is *undefined*.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm still learning JS and can't figure out what it is.  Any suggestions?

---

Edit: Here is what I'm passing to the function:

```
var uName = document.getElementById("unionname");
var noUnionName = isTextFieldEmpty(uName);
```

'unionname' is the id of the texfield that I'm trying to validate.  Here is the relevant HTML:

```
    <div class="formBox">
        <label for="unionname">Union Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="unionname" id="unionname" value="" class="wide"/>
        <span class="feedback good">Sample good message</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems ok... are you sure the parameter you are passing actually contains a text field?

Comment: @Andrea It doesn't seem to be...  Hmmm.  That's not good.

Comment: what are you passing to your `isTextFieldEmpty()` function?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Are you making sure to wait until the DOM is ready to call your function? Can you post the relevant HTML that you're using?

Comment: @jnpcl  Like I said, I'm just learning, so I'm not really sure if I can answer that.  Those variables are declared in a function that is called after window.onload finishes.  I'm trying to make the form validate using .onblur.  I left it out in this example because it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: @GnomeSlice is `unionname` the value of the `id` attribute on the textfield you are trying to validate?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `var val` locally in that function. Try declaring it globally by putting it at the top of your script; don't need to set it, just declare it.

Comment: I only need it in that function though.  I shouldn't have to declare it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it working.  Seems that the validation function was fine; the problem was in the way I was calling it.

```
window.onload = justDoIt;

function justDoIt() {

    var uName = document.getElementById("unionname");

    uName.onblur = function(){
        clearMessages(uName);       // clear out old feedback for this field

        var noUnionName = isTextFieldEmpty(uName);
```

This is how I ended up calling the function.

---

Ironically, it seems that the faulty .onblur code that I left out of my previous example may have been the cause of my problem.  But I'm really not sure.